# Copy Directories through dockerfile with same privileges and ownership into the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a directory and various files and directories inside that directory.

The ownership and group varies of some files directories.

I created a Dockerfile. I have created exactly the same user and group with the same uid and gid in Dockerfile.

So the container created will also have the same user and group with the same uid and gid as host.

The Image is built successfully as also container. When I See inside the container the ownership of all the directories and files are (root root).

I need the exact same ownership for each and every file and directory as of host.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The container has its own `/etc/passwd` file, and an image can generally be run on multiple hosts.  Since the container is isolated from the host, there's not really a need for the container's user ID space to match any specific host's.

Answer (score 0):

the root user will be always the owner of the files after copying the files to the docker image.

It is a best practice to fix the file permission after copying or adding files to the Docker images.

```
ONBUILD ADD . /application
ONBUILD RUN chown -R rails /application
```

you don't need to care about the file owners on the host system, because all files will be available inside the docker container and the only thing that you should do is to make sure that the user running in the container has access rights to the files.

The only case that file permission need to be aligned between the host and the docker containers is the case where both the container and the host are sharing some files.